# Is it possible to host web page with angular.min.js functionality using nodes http module

Tags: node.js, angularjs, http

Is it possible to host web page with angular.min.js functionality using nodes http module?

I'm making a really simple web project that is going to fetch some data and I decided to use angular.js to display data no the page. I tried to read index.html using fs module and sent it as response to the localhost. It seems that angular.min.js, that was included in the pages head section did not load as it would when I run the page in the browser from the file explorer.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. Also, check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

angular is a web application, so, please serve the angular using your node.js server and load the app in the web browser.

add a listener of get then send all files that index.html need, it is done.

or use `app.use(express.static('public'));` which public is your 'public' folder, put all file in dist to serve as a static content.

I use the first option every time but it is trick but functional.
sample code is:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');
router.get('/:id',(req,res)=>{res.sendFile(path.join('/path/to your/file/'+req.params.id));});
router.get('/',(req,res)=> res.sendFile(path.join('/path/to/your/file/index.html'));});
module.exports = router;
```